# Dimension of certain subgroup of isometry group of positively curved manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a closed $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold with positive sectional curvature.
Let $G$ be a close subgroup of isometry group ${\rm Iso}(M)$. Suppose the action of $G$ on $M$ is not transitive, hence $M/G$ has dimension at least $1$.

By a theorem of Grove and Searle the symmetry rank  $${\rm symran}(M)\le [\frac{n+1}{2}]$$ 
I am wondering is there any upper bound for the dimension of $G$ mentioned above?

Comment: Why the downvote?!  It seems to me a reasonable question.  Perhaps it would help to define the "symmetry rank"  (=rank of the isometry group).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Forgetting positive curvature, if $\dim M^n/G=k$ then by looking at the transitive action of $G$ on the principal orbit one gets a trivial bound $\dim G\le \dim O(n-k)=\frac{(n-k+1)(n-k)}{2}$. This bound is realized for $k=1$ on a round $S^n$ and $G=O(n-1)$. As the sphere is positively curved this bound is sharp.

Addressing the comment below, the assumption of $M/G$ being a manifold is not a natural one in this context. It hardly ever happens when $M$ has positive curvature. In particular, by  a result of Wilking (Lemma 5 in ["Positively curved manifolds with symmetry"](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=IID&s1=623978&vfpref=html&r=13&mx-pid=2199227)) based on his connectedness principle, if the principal isotropy group $H$ is not trivial and $M/G\ne pt$ then $M/G$ has a boundary. If $H=1$ and $M/G$ is a smooth manifold then the $G$-action is free and hence  $rank G\le 1$ by Berger's vanishing theorem.

I should add that there is large literature on the subject of isometric group actions on positively curved manifolds (mostly by Wilking, Grove, Ziller, Searle and Rong) and I suggest you study it if you want to pursue these kind of questions. A good place to start is a survey by Wilking ["Nonnegatively and positively curved manifolds".](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=IID&s1=623978&vfpref=html&r=7&mx-pid=2408263)

Comment: Thanks for the example. I am wondering what if extra assumption "$M/G$ is a manifold" is impossed?